# C++ std::hash return type

Tags: c++, string, hash, size-t, stdhash

So I've been reading a lot of articles, documentation pages, posts, benchmarks, etc., concerning the use of `std::hash` and its standard implementations.

### Synopsis

Looking [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) it seems that `std::hash` will always return an `std::size_t`, which following from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is *at least* 16 bits or 2 bytes in size, though it is implementation-dependent.

But this concerns me. How can I use `std::hash` on strings then, if I cannot even have the guarantee that the hash will be at least 32 bits (and I would really like it to return 64 bits).

On my particular x64 machine `std::size_t` is defined as `long unsigned int`, but apparently this is not guaranteed when I deploy my program.

#### Qustion

Is there a way around this, so I can know for sure that I get a 64-bit hash returned from `std::hash` ?

#### Conclusion

Judging from the comments, `std::hash` will not be suitable. Thanks!

Comment: This is solved by making your own hasher.  In reality though, unless you are planning for this code to work on micro controllers, `std::size_t` will be at least 64 bits.

Comment: Have a think about how many strings are you going to want to hash vs the hash size  And also note tnat _"...Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the same input within a single execution of a program;..."_ so storing hashes (in a file or database) is not possible. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for? For example, a solution that always works? Or, a solution that works *if it compiles* but refuses to compile if its assumptions are violated? Something else?

Comment: Another problem is you can't be sure what algorithm `std::hash` uses. It might cause collisions on one system and not the other.

Comment: @NathanOliver you think so? It's for a game engine, and this particular question is concerning string hashing (for a variety of purposes). I am already using xx3hash but was wondering if I could use std::hash instead, thus diminishing my ever-growing list of dependencies.
So no - no shipping for micro-controllers! Desktop pc's, laptops, perhaps consoles at some point.

Comment: @harold compile-time assertions of `sizeof(std::size_t)` could work, though it would probably be followed by template specializations with `std::enable_if`.

Comment: @ワイきんぐ for desktops, laptops and consoles, it is exceedingly unlikely that `size_t` is less than 4 bytes.

Comment: @ワイきんぐ While there is no hard guarantee, iI haven't seen a non-64 bit `std::size_t` on a x64 machine

Comment: @NathanOliver `sizeof(size_t)` is 4 if your program is run under 32bit mod in Windows.

Comment: When you say string, I hope you mean `std::string`s, because [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash#Notes) it says that: *"There is no specialization for C strings. `std::hash<const char*>` produces a hash of the value of the pointer (the memory address), it does not examine the contents of any character array."*

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, I would use `std::hash<char>` for C-style strings. But I'm already convinced that `std::hash` is not sufficiently reliable for my requirements.

Comment: @rustyx Following from [here](https://exceptionshub.com/what-is-the-default-hash-function-used-in-c-stdunordered_map.html) it seems that `std::hash<std::string>` would use MurmurHashUnaligned2.

Comment: @ワイきんぐ  But only for GCC with a particular version of the C++ support library.  There is no guarantee that it will not change.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is defined to be able to hold the size of the largest object. That means if you're working on a system where `size_t` is 2 bytes, your strings are going to be very short. Usually `size_t` is the same size as a pointer, which is 4 bytes on a 32 bit system and 8 bytes on a 64 bit system. It's likely to be enough.

Having said that, if you think that's not enough, you can create your own `Hash` class, and everything in STL allows you to pass that custom class instead of specializing `std::hash`.